# how to create Template using DNN?

Tags: templates, dotnetnuke

I am new for DNN i dont know  how and where to create a page Template in DNN?

can anybody forward me some tutorial link?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the page that you want to export as template.
2. Click on "Current Page" tab in the ribbon bar.
3. Click export icon from within the tab.

[alt text http://images.devs-on.net/Image/G6LGebA9KoqLC20-MyWebsiteHomeAlp.png](http://images.devs-on.net/Image/G6LGebA9KoqLC20-MyWebsiteHomeAlp.png)

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is actually right. It seems to me that even though the template xml contains a skin reference the skin will not be visible when a new page is created with the template

```
 <skinsrc>[G]Skins/Corporate/agr-feed-detail.ascx</skinsrc>
```

I Hope someone has a solution for this issue, or is able to confirm this issue

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm it - I haven't figured out how to get the template to actually use the referenced skin though.  It's kind of sloppy to build a page with a template and then have to go in and finish it up.

It's no different if you build the XML yourself or create the template via export.

Answer (score 1):

If you have look at the decompiled source code of DotNetNuke.Web.UI and look for RibbonBarManager.SaveTabInfoObject method, you will see why...

Essentially, when you select a template as a base for a page, the only info the new page will inherit is the Pane data, (i.e. the modules configured in the template).

As seen here...

```
xmlDocument.Load(templateMapPath);
TabController.DeserializePanes(xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//portal/tabs/tab/panes"), tab.PortalID, tab.TabID, PortalTemplateModuleAction.Ignore, new Hashtable());
```

Yes, sloppy, annoying, incomplete... very dotnetnukey and TBH what I expect from their code really. Not a fan.

Comment: a quick hack to get around this would be as follows:

in AddPage.ascx.vb in the cmdAddPage_Click event, change...

   templateFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(PortalSettings.HomeDirectoryMapPath, "Templates\" + TemplateLst.SelectedValue)

to...

    templateFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(PortalSettings.HomeDirectoryMapPath, "Templates\" + TemplateLst.SelectedValue)

    Dim xdoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(templateFile)
    If Not (xdoc Is Nothing) Then
        newTab.SkinSrc = (From doc In xdoc.Descendants("tab") _
        Select doc.Element("skinsrc").Value).FirstOrDefault()
    End If